# error C2501: 'WINGDIAPI' : missing storage-class or type specifiers

Tags: opengl

I am trying to Mipmap Textures. Microsoft visual studio 6.0 gives the error below.

```
error C2501: 'WINGDIAPI' : missing storage-class or type specifiers


WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glAccum (GLenum op, GLfloat value);
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glAlphaFunc (GLenum func, GLclampf ref);
WINGDIAPI GLboolean APIENTRY glAreTexturesResident (GLsizei n, const GLuint *textures, GLboolean *residences);
WINGDIAPI void APIENTRY glArrayElement (GLint i);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a SNAFU of the Windows SDK. You must include `windows.h` before `GL/gl.h` on the Windows plattform. It's usually done by putting the `windows.h` include into a preprocessor conditional on the `_WIN32` definition

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#include <GL/gl.h>
```